# iText chapter font overrides paragraph font

Tags: java, groovy, itext

This is the code I'm using to build up my `Chapter`:

```
Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC)
Font paragraphFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL)
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(doc.title, this.chapterFont).setLocalDestination(title);
Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk), i);
chapter.setNumberDepth(0);

paragraphs.each { paragraph ->
    chapter.add(new Paragraph(paragraph, paragraphFont))
}

this.document.add(chapter);
```

When I create the document and write it to a file, the paragraphs show up with the same font (size 16 Helvetica) as the chapter title. Does the chapter title's font setting override something in the paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, I've made an example named [ChapterAndTitle](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ChapterAndTitle) that looks like this:

```
Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC);
Font paragraphFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is the title", chapterFont);
Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk), 1);
chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
chapter.add(new Paragraph("This is the paragraph", paragraphFont));
document.add(chapter);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The fonts of the paragraph looks OK. The only difference with your code sample, is that I'm creating a `Paragraph` object using a `String`. It's not clear what your `paragraphs` object contains. Maybe the font is defined at the level of your `paragraph` objects.